# fetch last three latest order amounts by each customer based on ordered dates

Tags: mysql, sql

fetch last three latest order amounts by each customer based on ordered dates and order the customer name in ascending and fetch first 15 records.

```
table name: order_table
columns:
order_id
ordered_date
cust_name
product
order_amount
```

**Given data:**

```
160001 01/01/2020 Richard Books 1120    
160008 01/02/2020 Richard Chairs 1340    
160016 01/03/2020 Richard Computer 1299   
160007 01/04/2020 Richard Desk 2929   
160013 03/01/2020 Benny Monitor 1149   
160010 03/02/2020 Benny Other Electronics 1449    
160004 03/03/2020 Benny Printer 2399    
160012 03/04/2020 Benny Software 3599    
160017 01/02/2020 Ram Speakers 5110    
160023 02/03/2020 Ram Bookcases 2330
```

required sample output:

```
Benny 3599 2399 1449    
Ram 2330 5110    
richard 2929 1299 1340
```

**My code:**

```
SELECT 
    order_table.cust_name,
    (SELECT 
            MAX(order_table.ordered_date)
        FROM
            order_table
        GROUP BY order_table.cust_name
        ORDER BY ordered_date DESC
        LIMIT 15)
FROM
    order_table
ORDER BY ordered_date DESC
LIMIT 15*/
SELECT 
    MAX(order_table.ordered_date)
FROM
    order_table
GROUP BY order_table.cust_name
ORDER BY ordered_date DESC
LIMIT 15;
```

how to handle this type of problem statement and break it down to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give the answer but not in the prescribed format, any helping hand to get the required output will be highly appreciated.

```
select cust_name,order_amount from order_table where ( 
    select count(*) from order_table as c
    where c.cust_name =order_table.cust_name and 
    c.ordered_date<=order_table.ordered_date
    )<=3 order by cust_name, ordered_date desc ;
```